# Using data received from Backend in Angular Highchart

Tags: angular, highcharts

This is how I have been displaying data in a stacked column highchart in angular 5.

```
series: [{
    name: 'DEF',
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
}, {
    name: 'ABC',
    data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
}, {
    name: 'MNP',
    data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
}, {
    name: 'ASM',
    data: [3, 5, 2, 3, 6]
}, {
    name: 'BCC',
    data: [2, 5, 3, 4, 6]
}]
```

Now, I have been trying that on initialization of this component I get data from backend and use it here. I am successful in getting data as shown below but dont know how to use it to display in high charts.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.metricService.getPluginMetrics().subscribe(data =>{     
      this.metricItems = data;
      console.log(this.metricItems[0].value);
    })
  };
```

[image: This is the console output for the console.log above]

Data is fetched from a json file at backend to mock an API for now and then converted into string and this is how the data is being returned.
[image]

This is some of the content of JSON file.

```
[
    {
        "name": "DEF",
        "value": [10, 20, 40, 60, 60],
        "type": "",
        "timestamp": 1533822125000
    },
    {
        "name": "ABC",
        "value": [5, 3, 4, 7, 2, 6],
        "type": "",
        "timestamp": 1533822125000
    }
]
```

At the angular frontend the object for MetricItem is

```
export interface MetricItem {
    name: string;
    value: string;
    type: string;
    timestamp: string;
}
```

Also I tried to replace

```
series: [{
        name: 'DEF',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
    },.......
```

with

```
series: [{
        name: this.metricItems[0].name,
        data: this.metricItems[0].value
    }
```

But this has no effect and chart is not displayed. Could you please tell how to approach this.

EDIT: As @Core972 suggested in comments I replaced

```
title: {
    text: 'Stacked Consumption chart'
}
```

with this

```
title: {
    text: this.metricItems[0].name
}
```

but the chart is not displayed.

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the issue.

Comment: Just to be sure it's a data problem, could you add a title to the chart parameters and look if the title appear. Also Highcharts require data as numbers so check if `this.metricItems[0].value` are really numbers and not strings.

Comment: @Core972 As I mentioned this.metricItems[0].value are actually string. I tried to do JSON.parse() but to no avail.

Comment: @Core972 I replaced the title with one of the parameters of the data received but the whole chart is not displayed.

Comment: @Shaurya no, you said that the JSON contains `"value": [10, 20, 40, 60, 60]`. So it's not a string. It's an array of numbers. Again, post a complete minimal example reproducing the issue.

Comment: @Shaurya update to  `data: this.metricItems[0].value.map(Number)` in series parameter. this confirms data will have value as array of numbers

Comment: @Deep3015 'property map doesnt exist on type string' is what the error is when i did as u said